How to decode Base64-encoded Protobuf data in JavaScript without a schema?
I am trying to scrape data from the betting site etipos.sk. The API response includes a Base64-encoded Protobuf string in the ReturnValue field.
Here’s an example of the API response:

{
  Result: 1,
  Token: '4c6a71e287a5499a54e7c284a5d9bd4d',
  ReturnValue: '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',
  Type: 'GetWebStandardEventsResponse'
}


The value I need is hidden in the ReturnValue field. I can decode the Base64 string, but I'm unable to parse the resulting Protobuf data without a schema.
Here’s the JavaScript code I’ve tried:
const axios = require('axios');

const start = async()=>{
    const response = await axios.post(
        'https://tipkurz.etipos.sk/WebServices/Api/SportsBettingService.svc/GetWebStandardEvents',
        {
            'LanguageID': 17,
            'Token': '4c6a71e287a5499a54e7c284a5d9bd4d',
            'CategoryID': '65',
            'Top': 50
        }
    )
    const base64String = response.data.ReturnValue;
    const decodedString = atob(base64String); // Decode Base64
    console.log(decodedString); // Output the decoded string
}
start()

I was able to decode message using cyberchef
Despite successfully decoding the Base64 string, I cannot parse the resulting Protobuf data without knowing the schema. Any assistance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

I'd expect that to be in the documentation of the API you're calling. How else is anyone supposed to know how to decode it?

BTW, calling an API is the opposite of web scraping.

It seem strange that an API would return an encoded protobuf rather than just including the data in the JSON directly. But maybe the API is just passing binary data through without knowing how to interpret it.

can you provide more info? what is the exact url and the exact request that returns this data? and what is the data you're trying to get?

How is this related to web-scraping?

@GTK i just updated the question

Here's how to decode the response:

Install protobuf.js ( npm install protobufjs ).
Go to https://tipkurz.etipos.sk/zapasy.
Locate apiContract.js:

Devtools (F12), press Ctrl + P (open file) > type apiContract.js.
OR find it under Sources > webpack:///modules/eTipCommon/api/proto/apiContract.js


Download/save apiContract.js and place it in the same folder as this script:


const root = require('./apiContract.js');
const axios = require('axios');

function decodeResponse(base64String) {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');
    return root.GetWebStandardEventsResponse.decode(buffer);
}

async function start() {
    const response = await axios.post(
        'https://tipkurz.etipos.sk/WebServices/Api/SportsBettingService.svc/GetWebStandardEvents',
        {
            'LanguageID': 17,
            'Token': '427d2c7c9eb0eaed4eff336beb21aec0',
            'CategoryID': 'x130',
            'Top': 50
        }
    );

    const base64String = response.data.ReturnValue;
    const decodedObject = decodeResponse(base64String);
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(decodedObject));
}

start()

